# Почему не выводится результат foreach?

Tags: java

У меня проблема следующая -
есть класс Person, у него есть List <Children.>. В классе Children есть int age.
У меня есть List<Person.>, из которого хочу получить список всех детей которым больше 18 с помощью стрима. Но почему - то не вижу вывода в консоль.
В foreach вижу, что age - это Integer, но вывода все-равно почему-то нет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

```
public static class Person {
        List<Children> children = new ArrayList<>();

        String name;

        Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        void addChild() {
            children.add(new Children(3));
            children.add(new Children(7));
            children.add(new Children(18));
            children.add(new Children(20));
            children.add(new Children(30));
            children.add(new Children(2));
        }
    }

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person("Kris");
        person.addChild();

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person("Mark"));


        personList.stream().flatMap(person1 -> person1.children.stream().
                        filter(children -> children.age > 17)
                ).map(children -> children.age)
                .forEach(age -> System.out.println(age));
  }
}
```

Comment: Сколько у Марка детей?

Comment: Я добавляла 6 детей, от 3 до 30 лет.

Comment: Не вижу. *(нужно ещё 7 символов...)*

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что не видите?

Comment: Не вижу где добавляли 6 детей.

Comment: Изменю код тогда сейчас тут, не дописала сюда метод добавления детей. В идее прописывала.

Comment: Добавила в текст код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Person person = new Person("Kris");
    person.addChild();

    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new Person("Mark"));

    personList.add(person); // <-- !!!
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Все получилось) Спасибо!

Comment: @SugarCaramel Пожалуйста. Успехов.